# "Invoke Maven 3" vs "Invoke top-level Maven targets"

Tags: maven, jenkins

In a **Free-style** project (not talking about Maven2/3 project) in Jenkins, I have two possible build steps:

- Invoke Maven 3
- Invoke top-level Maven targets

On different installations, I have different combinations of these (some have both, some have just one of these). I am trying to figure out where the differences come from.

Comment: did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @JakubBochenski nope :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Invoke Maven 3** is provided by the artifactory plugin whereas 
**Invoke top-level Maven targets** is a part of the standard jenkins distribution.

You would need to use *Invoke Maven 3* if you want the artifactory upload plugin to work smoothly.